# The treemap library in R isn't producing a graphic

Tags: treemap

The treemap library is producing a list that contains data that could be used to produce a tree map. The list output of rows that contain my index data, vSize, vColor, srdErr, and columns that correspond to x0, y0, w, h, and color. Running the code does not generate an error and it completes the run of the code without error. Perhaps I am missing another library that is needed to generate the graphical map?

I've made sure to convert the vSize variable to numeric. The categorical variables are character. No error code is generated, so there isn't anything to debug.

```
tm <- treemap(
  grant.fun.tm,
  index=c("category", "grantor"),
  vSize="amount",
  palette = "Reds",
  type="index"
)
```

This code is suppose to produce the grant dollars that I have accumulated in my program by granting agency by four arbitrary categories into which I've grouped granting agencies into. I don't see anything wrong with the code. What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question. The graphic is generating as I scrolled down my block of code, I see that it is rendering at the end of the code block for some reason, but can not be called up into the viewer by typing "TM" in the console for some reason.